# Uncaught ReferenceError: timerFunc is not defined

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome

```
function timerFunc()
{
alert("Howdy");
setTimeout("timerFunc()",5000);
}
timerFunc();
```

This simple function seems to be causing some kind of trouble, any idea why?

I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: timerFunc is not defined " error on chrome

Comment: Most likely the code is not running in global scope. Using `setTimeout` with a string requires the function to be defined in global scope.

Comment: Hi Felix! would you please show me how to make it work properly. i.e global space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function name itself without quotes:

```js
function timerFunc() {
  alert("Howdy");
  setTimeout(timerFunc, 5000);//<-- quotes removed
}
timerFunc();
```

You can also use `setInterval` for repetitive task:

```js
function timerFunc() {
  alert("Howdy");
}
timerFunc();
setInterval(timerFunc, 5000);
```

Comment: @Mrpoppins, what is the error? Did you tried running here, click `Run code snippet`

Comment: Its working fine here, must be the other code on page, or it needs to be defined in global space. I tried adding a simple alert("Howdy"); into code and even that isnt working,

Comment: @Mrpoppins, kindly share your file structure, also the partial code where the script is imported and invoked

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script   type='text/javascript'>
    function timerFunc()
    {
   alert("Howdy");
   setTimeout("timerFunc()",5000);
    }
   timerFunc();</script>

Comment: It was working all fine, it started showing errors suddenly, there is no syntax error. Must be some kind of error, unknown to me

Comment: @Mrpoppins, kindly note this change `setTimeout(timerFunc, 5000);//<-- quotes removed`

Comment: Yes I did, tried to run just <script>alert("hello");</script> and it isnt working, neither is there any error on chrome console

Comment: Extremely sorry, restarted chrome and the goddamn thing works (i dont know how), silly me

Answer (score 0):

```
function timerFunc() {
  alert("Howdy");
}
timerFunc();
setInterval( function() { timerFunc(); }, 5000);
```